# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 288, 432, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, image-classification

1. image loaded from dataset

```
training_set = image_dataset_from_directory(
      data_dir,
      validation_split=0.3,
      subset="training",
      seed=123,
      image_size=(img_height, img_width),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      label_mode='categorical',
      color_mode='rgb',
      shuffle=True,
    )
```

2. model

```
num_classes = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu',             
          input_shape=(10,img_height,img_width,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

3. model.fit_generator()

   model.fit_generator(
   generator=training_set,
   validation_data=testing_set,
   verbose=1,
   callbacks=callbacks,
   epochs=120
   )

Comment: `ConvLSTM2D ` needs 5 dimensions. `image_dataset_from_directory` loads 3-channel images and combines them into batches, so you get 4d inputs. You need to combine your 3d image tensors into 4d tensors, which will be batched and you get 5d input as you need for `ConvLSTM2D ` - (samples, filters, new_rows, new_cols).

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can do so ? I am quite new at this.

Comment: Why do you want to use `ConvLSTM2D`? What logic do you want to apply to group the images into sequences?

Comment: As far as i saw lstm is used for time series prediction or to predict the next frame from a sequence of images.But i wanted to see if i could use it to classify images.

Comment: If you want to classify images - use normal convolution and your code should work fine. If you want to predict the next frame from a sequence you need to create a shifted dataset. You can easily find tutorials on this topic, for example https://keras.io/examples/vision/conv_lstm/

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[ConvLSTM2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D) expects `5D tensor` as inputs with shape: `(samples, time, rows, cols, channels)` and mainly used for time series, sequence type of data.

For image classification, you need to change this code from:

```
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu',             
          input_shape=(10,img_height,img_width,3)))
```

to:

```
#Changed to Conv2D from ConvLSTM2D, and removed 10 from input_shape

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', 
                 input_shape=(img_height,img_width,3)))
```

Also use **SparseCategoricalCrossentropy** as a loss function for image dataset.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Please find [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) reference for detailed understanding on image classification.